# Java code in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to build a Chrome Extension with a form uploading an image like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <p><input type="file" name="image"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Mark"></p>
</form>
```

I would like the "action" of this form would be a servlet in JAVA that executes a code that transforms this image, and the response would be the image "transformed".

I've thought about other options like executing a JAR with contains the code that transforms the image, but I don't know if is this possible.

Is there any option to include a JAVA code that operates an image into another inside the Chrome Extension?

Many thanks from Spain.

Answer (score 1):

I am just keep my answer short and sweet.  It appears that as of now java is not supported in chrome extensions.  An issue was filed for the chromium project, which is the chrome browser.  The ticket appears current as the last post was just a few months ago, status still remains won't fix.  A number of threads point to this same article below:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30258

Comment: Please do not add the "Google Keywords" text to your posts. Stack Overflow already does an *incredible* job of getting things appropriately indexed by Google, and artificial efforts like that only hurt, and add 'noise'.

Comment: Understood, thought I would just mention the keywords that lead me to the ticket.  Seemed rather easy to find.